# Is there any limit on a POST request using Alamofire in iOS?

Tags: swift, networking, ios8, base64, alamofire

I'm sending a POST request with an encoded base64 image using Alamofire in Swift.

```
let requestURL = NSURL(string: Constants.kBaseURL + method)!

let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = Constants.kNetworkTimeout

self.networkManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: config)

self.networkManager!.request(.POST, requestURL, parameters: parameters)
    .authenticate(user: Constants.kAPIUSER, password: Constants.kAPIKEY)
    .responseJSON(options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) { (_, _, JSON, _) -> Void in
        var result = RequestResultModel()
        let responseContent = self.checkContent(JSON, method: method)
        result.setResult(responseContent.0, message: responseContent.1, content: responseContent.2, method: method)
        callback!(result: result)
}
```

The problem is that I can't send large encoded base64 images because I get a 'nil' response. I know my server can handle the request because it successfully worked using Android or PostMan on Chrome.

Encoding the image:

```
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(utility.cropAndCenter(image, width: 500, height: 500), 70) <---- NOT WORKING
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(utility.cropAndCenter(image, width: 100, height: 100), 70) <---- WORKING
```

Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Check the error parameter in responseJSON closure and chain `.validate(statusCode: 200..<400)`

Comment: Any luck solving this issue? I'm using the latest Alamofire version 3.3.1 and I encountered the same problem. 

It is really frustrating as nothing seems to indicate there is a limitation for POST parameters length.

I filed a bug in Github [1208](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1208) hoping the Author can provide some help with this.

Comment: I agree with @Kubba. You should print out the `response` and `error` in `responseJSON` and add them to your question. Then we'd be able to give you better info when trying to point you in the right direction.

Comment: This things occurs because your URLRequest times out.
If you have set timeOutInterval remove it and try